# How can I create my own domain instead of localhost:8888 MAMP

Tags: apache, mamp

How can I create my own domain instead of localhost:8888 MAMP

I use osx

In httpd.conf

I remove #

```
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

inmy extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:8888
<VirtualHost *:8888>
 DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
 ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8888>
 DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
 ServerName me.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

My mamp ports

```
Apache Port 8888
mginx port 8888
mysql port 8889
```

In my etc/hosts

127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 me.dev

then I restart mamp

but I still cant use me.dev/ . I dnt knw what did I do wrong

Comment: you define the same port and DocumentRoot for ServerName localhost and me.dev. Then maybe use one VirtualHost and ServerAlias?

Comment: can you give me example please ?

Comment: single VirtualHost with port 8888 `DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs` `ServerName localhost` `ServerAlias me.dev`

Comment: NameVirtualHost *:8888
<VirtualHost *:8888>
 DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
 ServerAlias me.dev
</VirtualHost>
so i deleted first one right ?

Comment: instead of one line `ServerName localhost` you write two lines: `ServerName localhost` `ServerAlias me.dev`